# Style a div using jsrender based on data

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jsrender

I'm using `jsrender` template engine to render a listview, but I don't know how could I set de background color of a '' based on a field of my data...

The data have the following format:

```
[{"abc":"foo", "color":FF02FF},{"abc":"bar", "color":550233},...]
```

My pseudocode:

```
<ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data--divider-theme="d" data-autodividers="true">

</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).one("pageinit", function () {
        getData("URL", function (data) {
            var generatedHtml = $("#template").render(data);
            $("#list").html(generatedHtml).listview("refresh");
        });

        $("#list").listview({
            autodividers: true,
            autodividersSelector: function (li) {
                var out = ...;
                return out;
            }
        }).listview("refresh");
    });

</script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">

    <li>
        <div class="colorDiv">MyDiv</div>
        <h3>{{:abc}}</h3>
    </li>

</script>

<style>
    .colorDiv {
        width:100%;
    }
</style>
```

So, I want to set the background-color of `.colorDiv` with the field `color` of my data.

I thought I could do something like:

`<div class="colorDiv" style="background-color:{{:color}}"></div>`

But this is a syntax error...

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does it say that is a syntax error? The `style="rule: {{:value}};"` format should work without any problems.

VS2012 complains that it isn't valid HTML, but that's only because it's not smart enough to parse the JsRender syntax fully. JsRender itself has no problem rendering inline styles like this.

Bear in mind you're going to have to prefix those color hex values with `#`, and for neatness close them off with `;` so something like `<div class="colorDiv" style="background-color: #{{:color}};"></div>` is probably optimal.

Also, you seem to be trying to bind the array of data directly to a single `<li/>`, where (assuming `#list` provides the outer `<ul/>`) you really want something like:

```
   getData("URL", function (data) {
        var generatedHtml = "";
        var template = $("#template");
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            generatedHtml  += template.render(item);
        });
        $("#list").html(generatedHtml).listview("refresh"); // Haven't used listview before. Maybe you can't bulk insert like this but need to insert items one at a time, inside the loop?
    });
```

Comment: You are totally right! I tried it now and it works as you say... Thanks for the suggestions!